# Python Beautiful Soup Not Operation

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I have a simple need. I just want to find out all the tags from a HTML source that has not locator type of 'input'. For example, I just just want to match

```
<input>
```

The above code should display a textbox.
Again, the above tag has no attribute with locatortype ='type'

How can I achieve this using findAll??

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think passing `None` as an argument does what you want:

```
soup.findAll('input', {'locatortype': None})
```

Comment: Hi Blender, I wanted to ask one more question... Do you happen to know how do I create a findAll for only textboxes (with type='text' or no type at all)

In short, I want to club these two calls in one-
soup.findAll('input', {'type': None})
soup.findAll('input', {'type': 'text'})